Is the Frechet derivative independent for two possibly non-equivalent norms, provided it exists?
Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces under the following, respective, pairs of norms: $\|\cdot\|_{E1},\|\cdot\|_{E2}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{F1},\|\cdot\|_{F2}$.
Suppose $\|\cdot\|_{E1},\|\cdot\|_{E2}$ are possibly non-equivalent. Same for $\|\cdot\|_{F1},\|\cdot\|_{F2}$.
Let $f:E \to F$ be a function. Suppose $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $x \in E$ with respect to both pairs of norms. Would the two different Frechet derivatives coincide?

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2015876/timeline#comment_4138419 Wlog $E=\Bbb R$ but for $F$, what about dropping the completeness hypothesis?

Why was this closed? I don't see how this question is lacking clarity or details? No one has given any reason why this question is "lacking clarity"

Yeah, I don't get the rush to close. This is an interesting question.

@copper.hat Do you understand what happened? Whichever mod did this, they left no comments whatsoever.

@SpencerKraisler Happens a lot. I don't get it.

Not mods; the closers list is publicly available.

@AnneBauval Could you please provide comment as to why you closed this question?

I find this question difficult and attractive but "possibly" vacuous, as alluded to in my first comment. I alone didn't close this question: a closure needs 5 votes.

This question is clear, but it is a PSQ.

@AnneBauval I disagree that this is a PSQ.
